# Supervisord can't stop celery, how to do the same using Monit

Tags: celery, django-celery, supervisord, monit

I can't stop my celery worker using Supervisord, in the config file, it looks like this:

`command=/usr/local/myapp/src/manage.py celery worker --concurrency=1 --loglevel=INFO`

and when I try to stop it using the following command:

`sudo service supervisord stop`

It shows that the worker has stopped, while it is not.

One more problem, when you restart a program outside supervisord scope, it totally loses control over that program, because of the parent-child relationship between supervisord and its child processes

My question is: how to run celery workers using `Monit`?

Comment: I'm about to setup my celery instances to use monit. Given that you asked this question a while ago, are you now using Monit successfully with Celery?

Comment: @Erve1879, I didn't have enough time to try Monit since then in that project, I just changed things to fit into the Supervisord usage. If you can reach a conclusion of how to do it in Monit, please let me informed, or add it as an answer to this question, that will be appreciated. Thanks!